# can two accessibility services from different app run concurrently?

Tags: android, sqlite, push, accessibility

I have implemented accessibility service to save push notifications. It is working fine but the issue is when I implemented this service in two diiferent apps then only one app which is registered before is saving the pushes and other failed for the same.
i am using sqlite for saving push msgs.

Comment: I am having same problem. Have you found any solution ?